# Como retirar borda de Input image

Tags: html, css, input

Eu estou usando um `input` de image para funcionar como um botão de favorito

```
<input type="image" class="btnFav" title="Favoritar" />
```

Só que ele fica com uma borda quadrada nele [image: Segue anexo]

Já tentei usar o `css` abaixo, mas nada funcionou.

```
outline-color: invert;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: medium;
-moz-outline-style: none;
outline: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
border: 0;
border: none;
```

Alguém pode ajudar, de preferência sem usar javascript, apenas com `css`.

Link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d63rrd2d/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema ocorre pois o `input type="image"` espera que exista um atributo `src`, ou seja, a definição da imagem deve ser feita diretamente no botão, o que faz com o que o `:hover` não tenha o efeito correto, pois a imagem de background estará "atrás" da imagem de `src`.

Para resolver o seu problema, basta mudar o input para `submit` e continuar usando as imagens de `:hover` que você já possui em css.

Ficando assim:

```
<input type="submit" class="btnFav" title="Favoritar" value="" />
```

Coloquei o atributo de `value` sem nenhum valor para que não fique a escrita padrão de "Enviar" por trás da imagem.

Note também que todo tipo de input possui css padrão que aplica borda e outline, para se livrar completamente, basta remover essas propriedades diretamente no css do input, deste modo:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    outline:none;
}
```

Ou apenas

```
input {
    border: none;
    outline:none;
}
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/d63rrd2d/2/

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, obrigado pela resposta e pelo aprendizado.

Comment: Não por isso! Seja bem vindo ao grupo =D

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte

```
input[type="image"]{
    outline: none;   
}

input[type="image"]:focus{
    outline: none;   
}
```

Boa sorte, qualquer dúvida pergunte via comentário

---

Fiz os testes no link que me passou e nenhum css é preciso para resolver o problema, faça o seguinte:

```
<div class="btnFav" title="Favoritar" />
```

Troque de input para div e tudo fica certo

Comment: Ainda assim não funcionou, como eu havia dito, eu já tentei com o `outline: none` na classe. Mas obrigado pela tentativa.

Comment: inspecione o elemente e veja se essa regra css realmente está sendo aplicada

Comment: Acabei de ver, está sim.

Comment: adicionou o border: none tambem ou não ?

Comment: Tentei com e sem, e continua na mesma.

Comment: recomendo postar o código completo do seu problema assim eu consigo testar aqui e ajudar mais

Comment: Eu editei a postagem com o link do JSFiddle.

Comment: editei minha resposta da uma olhada e testa de novo

Comment: De fato a borda sumiu, porém ele não realiza o hover. Não há troca de imagens quando se passa o cursor.

Comment: editei minha resposta da uma conferida

Comment: Bom, depois de ficar tentando por umas duas horas algo supostamente simples, consegui achar esse fórum e alguém para me ajudar, muito obrigado, agora funcionou, vou continuar frequentando aqui.